# Angular 2 Router Using BehaviorSubject Observable in Resolve

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, observable, angular2-observables

I'm trying to set up my router config using a Resolve that returns an Observable from a BehaviorSubject. I've tried this in both angular 4.0.0-beta8 and angular 2.4.8+router 3.4.8

Here's my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private _data: BehaviorSubject<Array<string>> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

    constructor() {}

    public getData(): Observable<Array<string>> {

        this._data.next(['test1', 'test2', 'test3']);

        let asObservable = this._data.asObservable().delay(1000);
        asObservable.subscribe((myData) => {
            console.log([myData, 'this console message DOES show up']);
        });

        // if I return here, my component's constructor and ngOnInit never fire
        // return asObservable;

        let fakeObservable = Observable.of(['test1', 'test2', 'test3']).delay(1000);
        fakeObservable.subscribe((fakeData) => {
            console.log([fakeData, 'this console message shows up']);
        });

        console.log([asObservable, fakeObservable]);
            /* console log output
            Observable {
                _isScalar: false,
                operator: DelayOperator,
                source: Observable {
                    _isScalar: false,
                    source: BehaviorSubject {
                        _isScalar: false,
                        _value: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
                        closed: false,
                        hasError: false,
                        isStopped: false,
                        observers: Array[1],
                        thrownError: null,
                        value: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
                    }
                }
            },
            Observable {
                _isScalar: false,
                operator: DelayOperator,
                source: ScalarObservable {
                    _isScalar: true,
                    scheduler: null,
                    value: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
                }
            }
            */

        return fakeObservable; // this WILL reach my component constructor and ngOnInit
    }
}
```

Here's my resolve

```
@Injectable()
export class MyResolver implements Resolve<Array<string>> {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Array<string>>|undefined {
        return this.myService.getData();
    }
}
```

Here's the router

```
RouterModule.forChild([{
    path: 'mypath',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve: {
        data: MyResolver
    }
}]);
```

And here's the component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<Span>My Component</span>'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        console.log('component constructor');
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.route.snapshot.data['data']); // ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
    }
}
```

This is probably not the best way of designing the interaction between the resolve and the service, so I'm very open to suggestions there. However, I might go crazy if I don't figure out why BehaviorSubject.asObservable() doesn't work, but the mocked observable does work.

Comment: What's the problem? "doesn't work" is no information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I thought about this one overnight, and realized that I was using the resolve incorrectly. The crux of the problem is that the router expects the resolve result to eventually be **completed**. The BehaviorSubject, even though it only has one value **at a time**, will never be *done*, because the value can always change. I changed `this._data.asObservable()` to `this._data.asObservable().first()`, and it started working. It seems so obvious now!

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to work with angular 5 , getting white screen

Answer (score 4):

For Angular 6+ to complete observable in resolver you need to do as follows:

```
this.myService.getData().pipe(take(1))

// or

this.myService.getData().pipe(first())
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working. The component at a different route isn't getting the emitted event from another component. Do I have to have a resolver for simple data sharing between components at different routes?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's a bug.

Reproduced it in a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XmjC2rJ20VQWCsfncVIc?p=preview

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private _data: BehaviorSubject<Array<string>> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

    constructor() {
      console.log('created MyService');
      console.log(symbolObservable);
    }

    public getData(): Observable<Array<string>> {

        this._data.next(['test1', 'test2', 'test3']);
        this._data.do(myData => {
          console.log([myData, 'this console message DOES show up']);
        });

        return this._data.delay(1000); // <-- won't work .. maybe an angular bug !!
        return Observable.of(['test']);
    }
}
```

Created a bug on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14614

Comment: I think I agree that this should be handled by the framework in some way, so I'm very interested to see what the feedback is on the bug.