# Angular 4 how to wait for httpclient complete

Tags: angular

In my application I have services (that are making calls to the rest service) that are inherited from the custom base service that is defining common methods and properties that are used across all other services. One of such parameters was base url for my rest service which was using a variable under environment. However now came in requirement that makes this url coming from the config file. So I would have to get it using httpclient, which presents an issue that now at the time when actual service is trying to use base url it is not yet resolved. Is there a way how to wait till that call resolves?
My code looks like:

base-service.service.ts:

```
export class BaseService{
    protected apiUrlBase: string;

    constructor(protected _http: HttpClient) {
        // some logic

        this.getConfigData()
          .subscribe(
            x => {
              this.apiUrlBase = x.apiUrlBase;
            }
          );

    }

    getConfigData(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(
          '../../assets/config.json'
        )
          .do(x => {
          })
          .catch(error => {
            alert('Unable to read configuration file:' + JSON.stringify(error));
            return Observable.throw(error);
          });
      }
}
```

some-data.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService extends BaseApiService {
    private get _someDataServiceUrl(): string {
        return this.apiUrlBase + '/api/v1/somedata';
    }

    constructor(_http: HttpClient) {
        super(_http);
    }

    getSomeData(): Observable<ISomeData[]> {
        return this._http.get<ISomeData[]>(this._someDataServiceUrl)
          .do(this.handleSuccessResponse)
          .catch(this.handleErrorResponse);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can wait in my service till apiUrl is getting resolved, or what should I do to be able to use my baseservice as well as use the data that child services are relying on to be resolved till they use it?

Comment: yes you can use the `completion` callback function inside the subscription, what exact issue you face. revise your post it confuses

Comment: @Aravind my issue is when I run getSomeData()  this.apiUrlBase is undefined b/c the promise yet didn't resolve. I need a way to delay these calls till the this.apiUrlBase is populated by base service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty is to make the URL base an observable itself and make sure nothing in the service can continue until it gives a value:

```
export class BaseService{
protected apiUrlBase: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
protected apiUrlBase$: Observable<string> = this.apiUrlBase.filter(b => !!b).take(1);

constructor(protected _http: HttpClient) {
    // some logic

    this.getConfigData()
      .subscribe(
        x => {
          this.apiUrlBase.next(x.apiUrlBase);
        }
      );

}

getConfigData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(
      '../../assets/config.json'
    )
      .do(x => {
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert('Unable to read configuration file:' + JSON.stringify(error));
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }
} 


@Injectable()
export class TestService extends BaseApiService {
  private _someDataServiceUrl(apiUrlBase): string {
      return apiUrlBase + '/api/v1/somedata';
  }

  constructor(_http: HttpClient) {
      super(_http);
  }

  getSomeData(): Observable<ISomeData[]> {
      return this.apiUrlBase$.switchMap(apiUrlBase => this._http.get<ISomeData[]>(this._someDataServiceUrl(apiUrlBase))
        .do(this.handleSuccessResponse)
        .catch(this.handleErrorResponse));
  }
}
```

But this is clearly very ugly. A better solution would be to make sure this base service loads and resolves before anything else in the application by creating an app initializer provider for it:

```
import { Injectable, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BaseService{
  protected apiUrlBase: string;

  constructor(protected _http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getConfigData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(
      '../../assets/config.json'
    )
      .do(x => {
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert('Unable to read configuration file:' + JSON.stringify(error));
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }

  public load() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       this.getConfigData()
         .subscribe(
           x => {
             this.apiUrlBase = x.apiUrlBase;
             resolve(true);
           },
           err => resolve(err)
         );
     });
  }
}

export function BaseServiceInitFactory(baseService: BaseService) {
  return () => baseService.load();
}

export const BaseServiceInitProvider = {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: BaseServiceInitFactory,
  deps: [BaseService],
  multi: true
}
```

then put that BaseServiceInitProvider right after your BaseService in your app module providers.

Comment: with the initialization provider do I need to do any changes to the services that are derived from BaseService?

Comment: if you mean, services that have it injected, no, if you mean services that inherit from it, then probably, I would never think to do such a thing.  You could instead just make the base service into a config service that is injected into your other components / services that need config values, then you can treat any config related value in the same way app wide, no need to go through this ever again. load the config once, then inject it where it's needed, clean and consistent and not wasteful.

Comment: I just came back to this task and was wondering how should I modify my some-data.service.ts to be able to use latter solution (sorry if this is basic but this is my 1st angular 4 project after 2 years of .net only programming)

Comment: just call it a ConfigService and inject it into other services instead of having them inherit from it, donezo.

Answer (score 2):

Async/await may be one way to implement this. The constructor calls the async function "setApiUrlBase", which waits for "getConfigData" to resolve the HTTP response of config file before setting the API Url. My personal opinion is that you should make your REST endpoint fixed so you do not need to make two HTTP requests everytime when one is sufficient, but it depends on how you want to implement it.

```
export class BaseService {
    protected apiUrlBase: string;

    constructor(protected _http: HttpClient) {
        this.setApiUrlBase();
    }

    async setApiUrlBase() {
        await this.getConfigData().then(
            response => {
                // Promise successful
                response.subscribe(
                    x => {
                        // Subscription successful
                        this.apiUrlBase = x.apiUrlBase;
                    }
                )
            },
            err => { 
                // Promise fail error handling
            }
        );
    }

    getConfigData(): Promise<Observable<Response>> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            let r : any;
            this._http.get('../../assets/config.json').subscribe(
                response => {
                    r = response;
                },
                error => {
                    // Config error handling
                },
                () => {
                    resolve(r);
                }
            )
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The requirement is coming from the management b/c this is the way they always done switching between environments for the .Net apps. It actually causes a lot of trouble b/c of human factor but this is not the battle I want to fight now b/c being relatively new guy on the team. Instead I am trying to introduce autobuilds for different environments and with time make "human readable", "human changeable" configs and manual builds obsolete.

Comment: I understand. That is the mindset of some of my clients as well. In any case, if you only need to run once to get the config, then do as Bryan says and make it a injectable config service, or use some storage method like localStorage to save the url. Good luck!

Comment: what is `r` in `r = response;` ? I am getting compilation for cannot find name `r`.

Comment: I think I forgot to define it. It's supposed to be a resolvable response from a json file, so something like { apiUrlBase : string } but could be anything depending on your code. In the end just ensure getConfigData() returns the credentials you need from your main function call.